# How open edx stores course content data in mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, openedx, database

I am working on online course ware website which is similar to open edx.

Course ware data is stored in mongo database, I want to find out amount of disk space taken by each course.

The database is **edxapp** which contains following collections:
1. **modulestore**
2. **fs.files**
3. **fs.chunks**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: `edxapp`

`db.modulestore.find( { "_id.category" : "course" }, {'name':'1'} )`

Take a look at this page, in the section Mongo: 
https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Shell-commands

Answer (score 4):

Recently, the Open edX modulestore was [split into three sections](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-developer-guide/en/latest/modulestores/split-mongo.html).

```
use edxapp
```

To see the courses:

```
db.modulestore.active_versions.find().pretty()
```

To see the course structure which contains the course itself, sections, subsections, and units as blocks:

```
db.modulestore.structures.find().pretty()
```

Finally, to see the course definitions which contain the actual HTML content of the units:

```
db.modulestore.definitions.find().pretty()
```

In order to check the size of any of those collections, simply run:

```
db.<collection.name>.stats()
```

This will output the `storageSize` of the collection.